# Make URLS friendly

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Actually i got easy admin, and my urls are looking like :

```
/dashboardcrudAction=index&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CCrud%5CThemeCrudController&menuIndex=0&status_id=1&submenuIndex=-1
```

What can i do to make urls more user friendly ?
Something like :

```
/dashboard/Post
/dashboard/Post/2
```

Actually, easy admin is not used to be a back office. I use it as a dashboard for every user with custom request, that's the reason i want url more friendly.

Thank for your help.

Comment: I don't think it's doable without making a huge mess

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from a collaborator's response here: https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/4144#issuecomment-765648335

It's not possible to redesign Easy Admin URLs